# Modify Countup Timer To Include Currency Formatting In Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple countup timer that takes a starting number and randomly counts up. However, it doesn't work correctly on numbers that include decimals and commas.

How can I modify this to count up correctly in cents?

For example I want to count starting at the number 1,234,567.15 and every 500 milliseconds it adds a random amount of cents to the end. Then when it goes over 99 it adds to the dollar value.

Current Usage:

`<span>$</span><span id="counter">1,234,567.15</span>`

Javascript:

```
<script>
var timer;
function startCount() {
    timer = setInterval(count, 500); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}
function count() {
    var do_wait = Math.ceil(4 * Math.random());
    if (do_wait == 4) {
        var rand_no = Math.ceil(4 * Math.random()); // 4 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 4.
        var el = document.getElementById('counter');
        var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
        var newNumber = currentNumber + rand_no;
        if (newNumber < 99999999999) {
            el.innerHTML = newNumber;
        }
    }
}
startCount(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseFloat doesn't process ',' ,it will stop parse will met ',';

the best way is to use newNumber.toLocaleString()

```js
var timer;

function startCount() {
    timer = setInterval(count, 500); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}

function count() {
    var do_wait = Math.ceil(4 * Math.random());
    if (do_wait == 4) {
        //  var rand_no = Math.ceil(4 * Math.random()); // 4 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 4.
      var rand_no = 4 * Math.random(); //if you also want cents change,take this and comment previous line
        var el = document.getElementById('counter');
        var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ''));
        var newNumber = currentNumber + rand_no;
        if (newNumber < 99999999999) {
            el.innerHTML = Number(newNumber.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString();
        }
    }
}
startCount();
```

```html
<span>$</span><span id="counter">1,234,567.15</span>
```

if not work ,process it manually:

replace ',' to '' and calculate the number and add ',' back:

```js
var timer;

function startCount() {
  timer = setInterval(count, 500); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}

function count() {
  var do_wait = Math.ceil(4 * Math.random());
  if (do_wait == 4) {
    // var rand_no = Math.ceil(4 * Math.random()); // 4 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 4.
    var rand_no = 4 * Math.random(); //if you also want cents change,take this and comment previous line    
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ''));
    var newNumber = currentNumber + rand_no;
    if (newNumber < 99999999999) {
      el.innerHTML = processNumber(newNumber);
    }
  }

  function processNumber(num) {
    let strArr = num.toFixed(2).split('.')[0].split(/|/g).reverse();
    let result = strArr.map(function(v, index) {
      return index % 3 === 0 ? v + ',' : v;
    }).reverse();

    return result.join('').replace(/,$/, '.') + num.toFixed(2).split('.')[1];
  }
}
startCount();
```

```html
<span>$</span><span id="counter">1,234,567.15</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it does work for counting large numbers, but doesn't count in cents (before the decimals) it starts counting after the decimals.

In my example of 1,234,567.15 the .15 at the end never changes. Only the numbers that come before it.

Comment: @RyanThames because you used Math.ceil ,that make the increment is integer,if you don't ceil or floor ,you can get decimals.so ,you want cents change or not?

Comment: @RyanThames give you two choices,run the demo you will see,you can choose cents change or not by comment the code var rand_no=,,,,